multiplying both sides by cos to solve a trigonometric equation


This is from Richard Rusczyk's "Art of Problem Solving: Prealgebra". So What I wanted to know was...how come in Picture 1 solving the equation 2.38, he doesn't need to check that multiplying both sides by $3{(cosx)}^{2}$ introduces extraneous solutions?
In Picture 2, how come here solving the equation in problem 3.1, he has checked that multiplying by cosx introduces extraneous solutions?
He did not apply the test to the first - was this because of some niche little fact I didn't pick up? I always assumed that when you multiply or divide by a trig function ANY TIME, you need to check at the end you didn't add some funky solutions.
Thanks guys

In picture 1, he probably found it obvious that if $\cos\phi=0$ then $3\sin\phi\ne-2\cos^2\phi$.
